# Package upload fail : No Component named markup found?

Tags: managed-package, beta-managed-package

We are getting this weird error when trying to upload package.
While we keep repeating the process 2-3 times to upload , we managed to upload package successfully.

Following message we get on email

> A change was made to the package after the upload was initiated.
>   Upload the package again.

We are not sure why this error comes up while uploading the package, as we did not change anything after we click on upload button.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Log a case with Salesforce Support (In my case it helped to change API version of component to something like 43/44/45)

Answer (score 1):

We've been seeing this issue as well.  Salesforce has told us there is an issue that is affecting many partners/ISV and a KI is in the works.   Which doesnt solve our problem as we cannot create a package for our customers